# Existence of a monotone sequence within a set( bounded above) with its limit as supremum of set.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I think it is not always true. Because consider the set of negative integers ( which is an infinite subset of R ) whose supremum is -1. One can easily see that no such sequence exists.

> Q.Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $R$ that is bounded above and let
>   $u=SupA$.    Show that there exists an increasing sequence $(x_n)$ with
>   $x_n\in A \forall n \in N$and such that $u=lim(x_n)$.

Still it was asked to prove in this question from Introduction to Real Analysis by Bartle and Sherbet. Is there a fallacy in my logic?

Comment: $(x_n)$ with $x_0 = -2$ and $x_n = -1$ for all $n > 0$ is an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By increasing they probably mean $x_n \geq x_m$ if $n > m$. This is different than strictly increasing, which means $x_n > x_m$ if $n > m$. You can probably see how your counterexample would fail in this definition of increasing.